# Why is PyAudio running so slow?

Tags: python, performance, batch-file, speech-to-text, pyaudio

The following are scripts that together act as a live speech-recognition software. One is in python, and the other is in batch (Windows). It uses PyAudio.

Whenever I first created them, they worked fine. But now, they run really really slow, and I don't know why. It takes forever to start up, and takes roughly 30 seconds to convert the speech to text, whereas before it took a mere 3 seconds. I don't know if it's a problem with my computer (which I doubt because they worked fine before), or buffering problem.

Speech to text (speech.py):

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        file = open("output.txt", "w")
        file.write(format(text))
        file.close()
    except:
        file = open("output.txt", "w")
        file.write("null")
        file.close()
```

Live speech to text (test.bat):

```
@echo off

:start
%~d0
cd "%~dp0"
cd Python
goto loop

:loop
python speech.py
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (output.txt) do (set output=%%a)
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo %output%
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
goto loop
```

As you can see, the one that I execute is test.bat, and test.bat starts speech.py in a loop, making it live, as in it will output your speech onto the screen in text as you speak.

But why is it running so slow?

Comment: You can add a system timestamp print statement before and after this line > text = r.recognize_google(audio) : it will tell you the time taken by this api to respond back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking recognize_google() to recognize any speech in the audio.

Depending on your **internet connection speed**, you may have to wait several seconds before seeing the result.

Comment: Oh. I was not aware that PyAudio used API. I'm new to this. Is there a recognize method in PyAudio that doesn't require an internet connection?

Comment: You can check the offline and the online speech recognition libs. (https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) Note: offline ones are not so accurate.